# CKFetchRecordChangesOperation - moreComing

Tags: ios, ios8, cloudkit

```
changesOperation.fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock = ^(CKServerChangeToken *serverChangeToken, NSData *clientChangeTokenData, NSError *operationError){

    //encode and save token

    NSData *encodedServerChangeToken = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:serverChangeToken];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:encodedServerChangeToken forKey:fetchToken];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



    //handle more - **this causes a retain cycle**
    if(changesOperation.moreComing){

    }

};
```

Hi just wondering in the fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock, the docs say:

> If the server is unable to deliver all of the changed results with this operation object, it sets this property to YES before executing the block in the fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock property. To fetch the remaining changes, create a new CKFetchRecordChangesOperation object using the change token returned by the server.

In the code above this causes a retain cycle so how should this be handled and when recreating the operation is it possible to use the same completion blocks alreay created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define a weak changesoperation like this

```
__weak CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation *weakChangesOperation = changesOperation;
changesOperation.fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock = ^(CKServerChangeToken *serverChangeToken, NSData *clientChangeTokenData, NSError *operationError){
    ...
    if(weakChangesOperation.moreComing){
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, seems a bit weird for a standard api though, so for creating a new fetch operation how do I reuse the blocks already in place?

Comment: Just put all the operation code in a function and call that function again. You do have to save the changtoken somewhere (in NSUserDefaults) so that you can use it as the previousServerChangeToken. I do have sample code for this on github, but it's written in Swift. See https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao Saving the changetoken is tricky. You have to use the NSKeyedArchiver to archive and unarchive it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, EVCloudKitDao looks great

Comment: @EdwinVermeer why to define "changesoperation" weak?

Comment: The fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock will be reused. That would cause the changesOperation not to be released when it's finished. Since the inner call would also not clean it up it would remain in memory. By declaring it week it will be cleaned up as soon as it is finished. The inner call will just continue since it has its own reference.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer if assign _weak I get this warning: Assigning retain object to week variable; object weill be released after the assignment